# Find the extremal of the given function. CSIR -DEC 2018

Tags: calculus-of-variations

$j[y]=\int_{0}^{1}[(y')^{2}-(y')^{4}]dx$ ,subject to condition $y(0)=0,y(1)=0.$A broken extremal is a continuous extremal whose derivative has jump discontinuities at a finite number of points.Then whichof the following is /are true?

> - 1).There are no broken extremals and $y=0$ is an extremal.
> - 2).There is  a unique broken extremal.
> - 3).There exist more then one and finitely many broken extremals.
> - 4).There exist infinitely many broken extremals.

Here the Extremal function will be $y=ax+b$ type but if we apply the boundery conditions then we get  $y=0$ , answer should be' $1$' option but answer is '$3$' ,i am not getting the right answer please help

thank you.

Comment: Is the answer option 3 or is it option 4?

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770855/finding-broken-extremals-of-the-functional

Comment: @S.S last option......