# Finding broken extremals of the functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations

$J[y]=\int_{0}^{1}[(y')^{2}-(y')^{4}]dx$ ,subject to boundary conditions $y(0)=0,y(1)=0.$

A broken extremal is a continuous extremal whose derivative has jump discontinuities at a finite number of points. Then which of the following is /are true?

> - 1).There are no broken extremals and $y=0$ is an extremal.
> - 2).There is  a unique broken extremal.
> - 3).There exist more then one and finitely many broken extremals.
> - 4).There exist infinitely many broken extremals.

Here the smooth extremal satisfying the boundary conditions is clearly $y=0$, but how can I investigate the broken extremals here?

I tried using the Weierstrass-Erdmann Corner conditions and it seems there are no broken extremals at all. So I want to go with the first option. But the answer key says option 4.

**EDIT**

Utlilizing the vital comments below, I actually got broken extremals. But I am still stuck with the number of extremals that should exist here. Here's a rough sketch of my understanding.
[image]
But I am missing out on something.
Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you expand how you have used the WE conditions? They will actually show the existence of broken extremals with the slope $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so the mistake is somewhere in your calculations/interpretations.

Comment: @A.Γ.  I got $F_{y'}=2y'-4y'^3$ and $F-y'F_{y'}=3y'^4-y'^2$, where $F$ is the given functional I tried solving them simultaneously for equality on the right and left hand limits at the corner point. Kindly point out where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It is a right approach. Solve the system $\omega_1-2\omega_1^3=\omega_2-2\omega_2^3$, $3\omega_1^4-\omega_1^2=3\omega_2^4-\omega_2^2$ for $\omega_1\ne\omega_2$.

Comment: @A.Γ. I got it! It was a computational error. I got precisely two broken extremals now. So will it it be wise to rule out option 4 and go for option 3?

Comment: No. You've got two possible slopes at a corner. Now try to figure out how to make arbitrarily many corners if you know that between corners it is straight lines (from the E-L equation). Think like wwww.

Comment: @A.Γ.  But should I not confine myself to the interval [0,1]  due to the given boundary conditions?

Comment: Yes, you should, however it is still possible. Think the shape of extremals like wwwwww

Comment: @A.Γ. Is that possible within the interval [0,1] itself? If yes, then I am unable to perceive it. :( 
:(  Please can you elaborate a bit on the figure?

Comment: Given the slope, one possibility is to go up to x=0.5 then down. Next possibility: go up to x=0.25 then down up to x=0.5, then up again and then down. Can you continue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111101/discussion-between-shatabdi-sinha-and-a-).